# Change Symbol Borders in R Legend

Tags: r, symbols

I have made the following legend using pch = 22 and lty = 1:

[image]

I would like to change the border type of a few of these pch 22 symbols to a dotted line. Seems like there should be a fairly simple solution to this but I cannot figure it out.

My code is as follows:

```
plot(1, type = 'n')
legend("top",legend=c("CU","SL","SU","L","F"),lty=c(1,1,1,1,1),
       pch=c(22,22,22,22,22),pt.cex=4,cex=1.5,
       col=c("red","blue","green","orange","grey47"),        
       pt.bg=adjustcolor(c('red','blue','green','orange','grey'), alpha.f = .5),
       bty='n',horiz=T,lwd=c(2,2,2,2,2),x.intersp=0.5)
```

Comment: You can change the linetype to 3 for some of them, but that doesn't change the pch border. I've never seen that actually. The pch are usually so small that this doesn't seem reasonable. If it really matters that much, you could make little `rect`s and change the border line type?

Comment: I don't see any formal parameter for `legend` that is documented to affect the line type of the rectangles. Furthermore you forgot to quote some of those colors. There would be the possibility of _not_ using pch (since that uses `points`) and instead hacking the code for parameters passed to the `rect` and internal`rect2` functions.

Comment: My suggestion to hack the code is failing in my hands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One hacky option is to use Unicode symbols to get what I hope is something close to what you're after.

We need to plot the legend twice to make this work. First, we plot the legend without any border on the two leftmost boxes by changing the border color to `NA`. Then we plot the legend again, this time using the Unicode symbol for a dotted square for the two box borders we left out the previous time. I also had to manually adjust the `pt.cex` values so that the dotted box was the same size as the `pch=22` symbol.

I also had to use the "Cambria Math" font in order to get the dotted box to render properly. I've added commented out code to use that font. If you don't have that font on your system, you may need to try out a few different font families to find one that works with the desired Unicode symbol.

```
# par(family="Cambria Math")

plot(1, type = 'n')

legend(0.8,1.4,legend=c("CU","SL","SU","L","F"),lty=c(1,1,1,1,1),
       pch=rep(22,5),
       pt.cex=6.8,cex=1.5,
       col=c(NA,NA,"green","orange","grey47"),        
       pt.bg=adjustcolor(c('red','blue','green','orange','grey'), alpha.f = .5),
       bty='n', horiz=T, lwd=c(2,2,2,2,2), x.intersp=0.5)

legend(0.8,1.4,legend=c("CU","SL","SU","L","F"),lty=c(1,1,1,1,1),
       pch=c("\u2B1A","\u2B1A",NA,NA,NA),
       pt.cex=4,cex=1.5,
       col=c("red","blue","green","orange","grey47"),        
       pt.bg=adjustcolor(c('red','blue','green','orange','grey'), alpha.f = .5),
       bty='n', horiz=T, lwd=c(2,2,2,2,2), x.intersp=0.5)
```

[image]